# OpenCV Python calcOpticalFlowPyrLK returning points out of the camera frame

Tags: opencv, opticalflow

Running a 480x640 video through [the Lucas-Kanade optical flow tracker example](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/master/samples/python/lk_track.py), I'm getting some tracked points that are beyond the camera frame, like negative x and y coordinates. How is this possible? Is this a bug?

Comment: Please add code and results.

Comment: @A.Sarid sorry I forgot the link :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible and not a bug. There is `status` vector for valid and "lost" keypoints.

To be clear, the output coordinates of keypoints are a "prediction" of where they'll be, preserving of indexing from input keypoints.